# How to find checkbox value ( checked/unchecked) in iteamreander of data grid ?

Tags: apache-flex, air, flash

I have 3 checkboxes for calculating amount purpose. I used Datagrid within datgrid used

```
<mx:DataGrid>
    <mx:itemRenderer>
        <mx:Component>
            <mx:CheckBox id=mycheckbox  change="calc()"/>
        </mx:Component>
    </mx:itemRenderer>
...

public function calc():void
{
    statistic.dataProvider = mycheckbox.selectedItem;
}
```

but it's throws error like Call to possibly undfined method (calc)

Answer (score 3):

You can't give the checkbox an id the way you have done and expect it to behave as a single component.
When you specify the checkbox as an item renderer for a column you are not talking about a single checkbox. 
You will be dealing with as many check boxes as there are rows in the datagrid. 
The following example shows you how to determine if the checkbox in a particular row is selected or not

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml"
                layout="vertical"
                creationComplete="init()">
    <mx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
    import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;
    import mx.controls.Alert;

    private var ac:ArrayCollection=new ArrayCollection([
                                      {name: "John", test: true},
                                      {name: "Joe", test: false}]);

    private function init() {
        dg.dataProvider=ac;
    }
    public function check():void {
        var obj:Object=dg.selectedItem;
        Alert.show("Checkbox=" + obj.test);
    }
        ]]>
    </mx:Script>
    <mx:DataGrid id="dg"
                 dataProvider="{ac}"
                 click="check()">
        <mx:columns>
            <mx:DataGridColumn dataField="name">

            </mx:DataGridColumn>
            <mx:DataGridColumn>
                <mx:itemRenderer>
                    <mx:Component>
                        <mx:CheckBox label="Test"
                                     selected="{data.test}"/>
                    </mx:Component>
                </mx:itemRenderer>
            </mx:DataGridColumn>

        </mx:columns>

    </mx:DataGrid>
</mx:Application>
```

Sometimes flex seems to have trouble updating the data provider for the datagrid when you have a nested itemrenderer. You can explicitly set the appropriate property of the dataprovider row when the change event occurs on the checkbox as below;

```
<mx:itemRenderer>
    <mx:Component>
        <mx:CheckBox label="Test" selected="{data.test}" 
                     change="data.test=selected"/>
        </mx:Component>
</mx:itemRenderer>
```

Comment: Worked great! On the second part, was getting an error with change="data.test = selected", had to change it to change="data.test = !data.test"

Answer (score 0):

A checkbox does not have a "selectedItem" function or property...

mycheckbox.selected will return true or false based on whether or not sed checkbox is checked

Not really sure what you're trying to accomplish by setting a dataprovider to true or false, seems to me like you want to use a [RadioButtonGroup](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/2/langref/mx/controls/RadioButtonGroup.html)

Answer (score 0):

use `outerDocument.functionname` inside itemrenderer, and set the function as public. This is a limitation of Flex, Hierarchy mismanagement.